# Select a subset of a Pandas DataFrame based on a list of criteria built from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have the following DataFrame

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df_org = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
                           'B' : [1,1,1,1,2,2],
                           'C' : [1,2,3,4,1,2]})
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  2  1  2
2  3  1  3
3  4  1  4
4  5  2  1
5  6  2  2
```

And this another one, `df_criteria`, that has some of the columns of `df_org` and from which we will build our criteria. For instance:

```
>>> df_criteria = pd.DataFrame({'B' : [1,2], 
                                'C' : [1,1]}) 

   B  C
0  1  1
1  2  1
```

I'd like to be able to fetch the value of `A` in the `df_org` DataFrame for which the corresponding values of the `B` and `C` match the ones listed in the `df_criteria` DataFrame. In this examples, I would like to have a subset of `df_org` that contains its rows '0' and '4', like so:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
4  5  2  1
```

Being a newbie in pandas, the way I've implemented this is using the `for`-loop mindset: by iterating over the rows of `df_criteria` and querying `df_org` for each row. However, this is very slow and I have the impression that there must be a more pythonic (and faster) way that does not make use of `for`-loops. I've also explored the use of `DataFrame.lookup`, however it is not useful in my case because the indices in `df_criteria` and `df_org` do not necessarily match.

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple inner merge would work:

```
In [285]:

df_org.merge(df_criteria, on=['B','C'])
Out[285]:
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  5  2  1
```